# Google strikes after migrate account

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

I have a Google Play account with some apps published. I have 2 apps suspended in my account for policies infrigiment. My question is: if i transfer all of my healthy apps from one account to another, will they know about my past strikes ? I want a clean account without any strike!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a community for questions about general programming. Your question seems to belong on some other community, check out https://stackexchange.com/ to find the community that best fits your needs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.

Comment: How can i delete the post ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually,YES.

Google keeps track of everything.

You can open a new developer account for your further apps.